# R - Optimization (max)

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to copy over a solution from excel solver into R but not sure where to start.

The problem: 
 Choose 5 options for each hour (5 rows) that maximize the sum of "Score" without picking the same group 2 times across multiple hours.

In other words: 
 Maximize score, with criteria: 
 1. rows within same group only gets picked a maximum of 2 times. 
 2. rows within same hour get picked a maximum of 5 times.

I think it would be easier for me to explain this by showing you guys the results in excel:

[image: Question to Answer]

Data: 
group,hour,Score
 a,1,1000
 a,2,1231
 b,1,12312
 b,2,6438
 c,1,3033
 c,2,6535
 d,1,4283
 d,2,4957
 e,1,9507
 e,2,5115
 f,1,1914
 f,2,9278
 g,1,5362
 g,2,8408
 h,1,4640
 h,2,4296
 j,1,8115
 j,2,1143
 aa,1,3242
 aa,2,3695
 bb,1,3908
 bb,2,2540
 cc,1,6438
 cc,2,2170
 dd,1,6497
 dd,2,3327
 ee,1,5067
 ee,2,6614
 ff,1,5140
 ff,2,9858
 gg,1,8061
 gg,2,2316
 hh,1,7848
 hh,2,3525
 jj,1,8259
 jj,2,9014
 a,3,31100
 b,3,111100
 c,3,87200
 d,3,60700
 e,3,50600
 f,3,74300
 g,3,97400
 h,3,28900
 j,3,25900
 aa,3,55600
 bb,3,38200
 cc,3,58500
 dd,3,51300
 ee,3,84000
 ff,3,83700
 gg,3,74200
 hh,3,19700
 jj,3,62800

**Data in `dput` format.**

```
df1 <-
structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 15L, 
15L, 17L, 17L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 
10L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 14L, 16L, 16L, 18L, 
18L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 
2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 18L), 
.Label = c("a", "aa", "b", "bb", "c", "cc", 
"d", "dd", "e", "ee", "f", "ff", "g", "gg", 
"h", "hh", "j", "jj"), class = "factor"), 
hour = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Score = c(1000L, 
1231L, 12312L, 6438L, 3033L, 6535L, 4283L, 4957L, 
9507L, 5115L, 1914L, 9278L, 5362L, 8408L, 4640L, 
4296L, 8115L, 1143L, 3242L, 3695L, 3908L, 2540L, 
6438L, 2170L, 6497L, 3327L, 5067L, 6614L, 5140L, 
9858L, 8061L, 2316L, 7848L, 3525L, 8259L, 9014L, 
31100L, 111100L, 87200L, 60700L, 50600L, 74300L, 
97400L, 28900L, 25900L, 55600L, 38200L, 58500L, 
51300L, 84000L, 83700L, 74200L, 19700L, 62800L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -54L))
```

Comment: See the r packages ROI and ompr for optimization modeling in R.  They will allow you to do what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Using `lpSolve` package for this optimization problem with binary variables and linear constraints,

```
library(lpSolve)
library(data.table) #for pivoting data and shifting coef of constraints
d <- dcast(df1, group ~ hour, value.var="Score")
nr <- nrow(d)
nc <- ncol(d) - 1L

m1 <- matrix(c(1,1,1,rep(0, nr*nc-3L)), ncol=nc, byrow=TRUE)
max2constr <- do.call(rbind, shift(m1, 0L:(nr-1), fill=0))

m2 <- matrix(c(rep(1, nr), rep(0, (nc-1)*nr)), ncol=nc)
choose5constr <- do.call(rbind, shift(m2, seq(0, by=nr, length.out=nc), fill=0))

ans <- lp("max",
    unlist(d[, 2:4]),
    rbind(max2constr, choose5constr),
    c(rep("<=", nrow(max2constr)), rep("=", nrow(choose5constr))),
    c(rep(2, nrow(max2constr)), rep(5, nrow(choose5constr))),
    all.bin=TRUE)
ans$objval

soln <- matrix(ans$solution, nrow=nr, dimnames=list(d$group, names(d)[-1L]))
```

Objective value = 552826

`soln` output:

```
   1 2 3
a  0 0 0
aa 0 0 0
b  1 0 1
bb 0 0 0
c  0 0 1
cc 0 0 0
d  0 0 0
dd 0 0 0
e  1 0 0
ee 0 1 1
f  0 1 0
ff 0 1 1
g  0 1 1
gg 1 0 0
h  0 0 0
hh 0 0 0
j  1 0 0
jj 1 1 0
```

Comment: holy cow, so excel had it wrong? Thank you very much for your help, will go through this but I suspect I should be fine understanding everything.